# Infinite sums with Boole and EvenQ

Tags: summation, boolean-computation, prime-numbers

Suppose I am interested in a sum across a set of even numbers, such as:

```
Sum[x, {x, 2, 20, 2}]
```

> 110

or

```
Sum[ x  Boole[EvenQ[x]], {x, 1, 20}]
```

> 110

So far, so good.

HOWEVER, if I extend this to an infinite set, the first method works:

```
 Sum[ (x/x!), {x, 2, Infinity, 2}]
```

> Sinh[1]

... but the `Boole` method returns 0:

```
Sum[ (x/x!)  Boole[EvenQ[x]], {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

> 0

My interest in this comes from a question on the mathSE site:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055438/what-is-the-probability-that-a-poisson-random-variable-is-prime

where someone asks how to calculate the probability of a Poisson random variable being prime, and I was actually trying the same type of problem with `PrimeQ` ... and also getting 0. I wasn't expecting mma to get an answer ... but 0 is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably know this but in this case you can readily handle it manually: `Sum[x/x!, {x, 2, Infinity, 2}]`.  Search this site and you'll find a few examples of more complicated cases that cant readily be treated like that and unfortunately there is no general solution.

Comment: ???? `Sum[x/x!, {x, 2, Infinity, 2}]` has always been part of the question. Maybe you missed it?

Comment: doh! must work on reading comprehension

Answer (score 4):

With infinite sums, the summand is evaluated. Since `Q` functions ***always*** return `True` or `False`, `EvenQ[x]` evaluates to `False` since `x` is not an even integer.

You can use `Mod` instead and everything works fine for your examples.

```
Sum[x/x! Boole[Mod[x,2] == 0], {x, 1, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
> Sinh[1]
> ```

Comment: "Since Q functions always return True or False" --> I never realized this.  Is there no exception?  Is that the reason why `Positive` is not called `PositiveQ`?

Comment: Yes, that's why there's no `Q` at the end of `Positive`. The only (technical) exceptions I know of are `EllipticNomeQ` and `InverseEllipticNomeQ`. These are numerical functions that are denoted with a capital Q in literature.

Comment: @Szabolcs, looking at `Names["System\`*Q"]` it appears the functions `HypergeometricPFQ`, `MarcumQ`, and `QHypergeometricPFQ` fall under the same category as `EllipticNomeQ`. But the answer is yes, if a boolean function ends in `Q` then it always returns `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 2):

look at:

```
Sum[(x/x!) Boole[EvenQ[x]], {x, 1, Infinity}] // Trace
```

the function `Sum` (in the case of infinity `Sum`) try to organize its argument which result in some evaluation.

in this case, 
`Boole[EvenQ[x]]` evaluated to `0` because `EvenQ[x]` evaluated to `False`.